# VIM: Calling a function from insert mode with imap?

Tags: vim

I have a function that I've written in my vimrc to turn syntax off and set paste. The function looks like this:

```
function! ToggleSyntax()
if g:syntaxon == 1
syntax off
set paste
let g:syntaxon = 0
else
syntax on
set nopaste
let g:syntaxon = 1
endif
endfunction
```

I use the F12 key to call the function, and have mapped the function to F12 like this:

```
map <F12> :call ToggleSyntax()<cr>
imap <F12> <c-o>:call ToggleSyntax()<cr>
```

the problem that I'm having is that I can't call the ToggleSyntax function from insert mode. This is very confusing to me,  because I have used the imap handler, but still, this function only works from command mode. I can't figure out how to get it to work, any help with this would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Tip: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion; doesn't help with your problem here, though.

Answer (score 8):

For me, your function also turns *paste* on in insert mode, but it doesn't turn it back off (and syntax on). The reason is that when `:set paste`, **no insert mode mappings apply**. That's one essential aspect of `'paste'`, see also `:help 'paste'`.

The only way to toggle in insert mode is

```
:set pastetoggle=<F12>
```

(that option was explicitly made for this purpose) but then, you'll lose the parallel syntax toggling that your function provides.